# Visual Studio Team Services Build - Git Repository

Tags: build, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am leveraging Visual Studio Team Services Build Vnext to build ASP.NET application present in my Microsoft GIT Repository.

The Microsoft GIT repository is created under an Agile Team Project of the VSTS instance.

The VSTS build is getting executed successfully without any issues.

But I have a query with respect to the cloning activity of the GIT Repository that gets executed on the VSTS Build Agent.

During the build, the VSTS build Agent is cloning the entire master branch of the GIT repository instead of downloading the required ASP.NET application folder.

Is there a way to download the specific application folder on to the build agent instead of the entire branch.

we have this option for the onpremise TFS build having TFS as the Source control.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to pull only a specific folder on a git repository unlike tfsvc. This is why you don't have such an option for the build tasks.